# Get DateTime object from Phalcon Model for DateTime column in PHP

Tags: php, database, datetime, model, phalcon

In the database table there are some columns with `DATETIME` type. Is there any way I can get Phalcon Model to convert them automatically from string to `DateTime` object in PHP and vice versa without using `beforeSave()` and `afterFetch()`?

I tried to use annotation `@Column(type='datetime')`, but the data is still returned as `string`. And `@Column(type='boolean')` works fine for me though.

Could you please advise me on the right approach?

Comment: Apparently, you can do this: https://docs.phalcon.io/3.4/en/db-models-behaviors

Comment: What's your aversion to using `beforeSave()` and `afterFetch()`?  I think that, or the model behaviours are the only ways to do it.  As far as I know, there's no way built-in to Phalcon to trigger this transformation - you'll have to code it yourself.  If you want to get really fancy, you could possibly add this to your base model code and have it programmatically look through the model's meta-data and convert anything of type "datettime" to a DateTime object.  "boolean" and "string" are built-in types, which is maybe why boolean works and DateTime doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

@Ярослав Рахматуллин is one way to go

or you can use phalcon setters and getters ( much simpler way )

[check the documentation here](https://docs.phalcon.io/3.4/en/db-models#public-properties-vs-settersgetters)

and this an example of the implementation for you situation to my understanding

```php
use \DateTime;

class Foo extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
    // set your column property to protected
    protected $date;

    // will be called when protected property $date is accessed
    public function getDate()
    {
        // add your validation here to check if the date is not null
        return new DateTime($this->date ?: 'now');
    }

    // will be called when protected property $date is set
    public function setDate(DateTime $date = null)
    {
        // add your validation here to check if $date is not null
        if (!is_object($date)) {
            $date = new DateTime;
        }
        // this is mysql format for timestamp
        $this->date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        return $this;
    }
}

// find first row
$foo = Foo::findFirst();

// check if the row exists
if ($foo) {
    // $foo->date would return getDate()
    var_dump($foo->date); // DateTime object

    // this would call setDate()
    // column date will convert DateTime object to the format Y-m-d H:i:s
    $foo->date = new DateTime('2019-09-28');  // 2019-09-28 00:00:00

    $foo->save();
}
```